# How to report phishing on Firebase.com

Tags: firebase, phishing

We've received quite a number of phishing attempts that using firebase.com as a landing site. I cannot find any link to report such cases. Does anyone know how to report phishing on firebase.com?

Comment: As NRE said, your first priority is probably to report to SafeBrowsing (this'll eventually trigger a warning page for anyone trying to visit). But, that won't actually get the site taken down. For that, you need to report to the hosting provider (in this case Google). https://phish.report does a decent job cataloguing all the different report forms and finding the right one to report fraud to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following url:

https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/

Comment: Thanks @NRE, it is an alternative that we have been taken. Unfortunately, up to today, I not found a way to report phishing happened on firebase platform.